# Hibernate with Sql Server fail for nvarchar field with "No Dialect mapping..."

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate's JPA-Implementation to access our SQL Server 2012 database.

When trying to select a `nvarchar` field in a native query, I get an exception "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9".

It looks much like [No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9 with Hibernate 4 and SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149627/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9-with-hibernate-4-and-ms-sql-server-2011) or [No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279542/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9) but I couldn't find a solution for me there (both are not using JPA).

My database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE NvarcharExample(
    exampleField nvarchar(20) PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO NvarcharExample(exampleField) VALUES ('hello')
```

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
class NvarcharExample {

    @Id
    public String exampleField;
}

public class NvarcharTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String queryString = "SELECT e.exampleField FROM NvarcharExample e";

        // establish connection
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
        try {
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

            // access data using JPQL
            entityManager.createQuery(queryString).getResultList(); // works

            // access data using SQL (native query)
            entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString).getResultList(); // fails
        } finally {
            entityManagerFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>

            <!-- database connection settings -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>:<port>;databaseName=<databasename>" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="<user>" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="<password>" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

With sql logging enable, I get this output in my console

```
select nvarcharex0_.exampleField as col_0_0_ from NvarcharExample nvarcharex0_
SELECT e.exampleField FROM NvarcharExample e
```

I'm using

- `hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar`
- `hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar`
- `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`
- `hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar`
- `sqljdbc41.jar`

What I've tried:

- using a `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` makes it work, but I need `nvarchar`
- using jpql instead of sql works (see my example code), but I need a native query
- I tried `sqljdbc4.jar` in Version 4.0 and 4.1 and I tried `sqljdbc41.jar`
- I head about subclassing the SQL Server Dialect class, but did not have any success with that
- I added `<property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />` to my `persistence.xml` (right behind the password property)
- I added `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />` to my `persistence.xml`
- I changed the persistence provider to `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve that issue by subclassing the SQLServerDialect:

```
package packagename;

import java.sql.Types;

public class SqlServerDialectWithNvarchar extends org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect {

    public SqlServerDialectWithNvarchar() {
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, 4000, "string");
    }

}
```

and referencing it in my `persistence.xml`:

```
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="packagename.SqlServerDialectWithNvarchar" />
```

PS: It seems to be fixed with hibernate 5.1 according to this ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10183

Answer (score 9):

Using `@Nationalized` attribute helped me to map `String` to nvarchar for MS SQL 2012 without dialect subclassing.

At the same time setting the `hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data` property to true did not worked for me.

For futher information watch docs [National Character Types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch08.html#value-national-character-types).

Comment: Well, the JPQL query works fine, only the native query causes trouble. Where can I put "@Nationalized", when using a native query (no entity as result class)?